# During build a react native app their occur some problem

Tags: react-native

During build React native app facing some problem

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
  >    build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
  >    platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  >   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

Comment: The message gives pretty clear instructions on what to do. Have you followed them?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one line of code at your project file graldew with the following code

```
yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
```

This might help for [more detail](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/3687#issuecomment-455885806)